# Нет java при создание проекта в AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: as]

Почему нет выбора языка **java** при создание нового проекта?
И даже если я создаю этот проект у меня даже mainactivity.xml нет!
Помогите пожалуйста!

Почему кнопка находиться левее, а не в центре ?? Хотя в activity_main она находиться в центре?

Comment: вы создаете проект на Compose. он работает только с Котлином. выберите другой шаблон для нового проекта по типу "Empty Views Activity"

Comment: @Wlad спасибо за ответ! А что за build configuration language почему там только что-то с Kotlin'ом ?

Comment: @Palindrom это язык для грэдл-файлов. Раньше был groovy, теперь можно писать и на kts

Comment: @Circassian Почему кнопка находиться левее, а не в центре ?? Хотя в activity_main она находиться в центре?